# Side menu on UISplitViewController like Gmail iPad App

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

How to put a side menu bar on the UISplitViewController like Gmail iPad App?

[image]
[image]

Based on Apple Documentation on UISplitViewController, it always must be the root of the application. I have tried to put the UISplitViewController into a navigation controller and it doesn't work

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller

Can anybody guide me on how to achieve such layout? I am totally lost. Been figuring it out for days and still can't find any solution.

If there is any library out there that can help me to achieve this function, will also be so appreciated.

I am using Swift 4. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you eventually figure this out?  The closest example I managed to find is: https://github.com/nitingeorge227/NGSplitMenuController

Comment: @SebastianDwornik check my answer below see if it helps